# Laravel, InertiaJS, Vue3 - HMR doesn't work on ./resources

Tags: laravel, npm, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a Laravel 10 with InertiaJS and Vue3 (using Vite), project. It was working fine. Then an issue started to appear, with limitation of system watchers amount, which I fixed by running echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

Then I didn't worked on the frontend of the project for several days and now, when I'm modifying any file in ./resources, the HMR doesn't work. Not really sure if it's connected to the increase of watchers, but trying to be as detailed as possible.

The strange behavior is that when I edit js files in root, like ./vite.config.js, the changes are applied and HMR recompiles everything.

But when I edit any file in ./resources, it doesn't react at all.

More details:
OS: Ubuntu;
Using Laravel's sail (so running the sail npm run dev);
VITE v4.5.0;
LARAVEL v10.32.1  plugin v0.8.1;
Using Tabnine.